# Snakemake run docker container command

Tags: docker, snakemake

I have this problem I have a docker image of a program and I want to run some commands using that code.
I have rules that trasfrom input to comand script

```
rule create_maf:
    input:
        read="/data3/CALL/{sample}.muetect2.vt.clean.vcf.gz"
    output:
        out="/data3/MAF/{sample}.muetect2.vt.vep.maf"
   params:
         db_ens= "/mnt/mpwork/vep/homo_sapiens:/mnt/homo_sapiens",
         fst= "/mnt/homo_sapiens/87_GRCh37/Homo_sapiens.GRCh37.75.dna.primary_assembly.fa",
         tumor_id="{sample}",
         data="/home/data/TEST/:/data3"
    script:
        "scripts/report.py"
```

## this is the report.py

```
from subprocess import run

if len(snakemake.input) > 1:
    cmd = ['docker','container','run', '-it','-v', snakemake.params['db_ens'], '-v', snakemake.params['data'],'vcf2maf_87','perl','vcf2maf.pl','--input-vcf',snakemake.input['read'],snakemake.output['out'],'--vep-data', '/mnt/','--ref-fasta',snakemake.params['fst'],'--tumor-id',snakemake.params['tumor_id'],'--normal-id','NORMAL']
    run(cmd)
```

Inside /home/data/TEST/ I have CALL with all the samples... The problem they don't found....

Comment: Try creating a singularity image from the docker container. Snakemake has native support for singularity

Comment: @TheUnfunCat I tryed but I have some problems with the permission on singulairity. I mean if I import a machine from docker in singularity  the command not work in the same way..